# interpreting map-projection details

Tags: map-projections, proj

Not an expert in  reading or interpreting  map-projections. I have data set with the following description.

> The coordinates are in Albers Equal Area Conic projection, with the
>   following projection settings: Scale = 1; False Easting(m) = 5000000;
>   False Northing(m) = 0; Longitude Origin = 20; Latitude Origin = 0;
>   Standard Parallel 1 = 45; Standard Parallel 2 = 55, and the Ellipsoid
>   is WGS 84.

Is it the equivalent for *+proj=lonlat +datum=WGS84*

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, why would you think they're equivalent, completely different in fact.

Try: `+proj=aea  +lat_1=45  +lat_2=55  +lon_0=20  +x_0=5000000  +datum=WGS84`

https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4/wiki/GenParms

Comment: Note that the `datum` argument should be capitalized, i.e., `+dataum=WGS84`

Comment: @Matifou Agreed, most unfortunate. I've fixed the one, and removed the other. See [this advisory](https://madfileformatscience.garymcgath.com/2016/09/08/libtiff-offline/).